# Can't compile java files from CLI (Selenium JUnit)

Tags: java, selenium, junit, command-line-interface

I try to compile java files using CLI for run test cases

On my test case java file, I import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver and others.

While compiling I got the error message:

```
  "error: package org.openqa.selenium does not exist
```

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;"

If anybody knowns a reason ?

I using this command :

```
  javac -cp junit-4.13.jar;. file1.java
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need the `selenium-java` jar and all its dependencies as well added to the classpath. At the moment you're specifying only the `junit` jar in the classpath. Hence, the error for package not found.

Some of the dependencies of `selenium-java` would be :

```
guava
okhttp
okio
buddy
commons-exec
selenium-api
selenium-chrome-driver
selenium-edge-driver
selenium-firefox-driver
selenium-ie-driver
selenium-opera-driver
selenium-remote-driver
selenium-safari-driver
selenium-support
```

You can use some build automation tool like `maven` or `gradle` for dependency management.